# How can I tell a For Loop to do something based on an object's custom property?

Tags: python, properties, loop

I have two spheres, both have a `MATTYPE` custom property, one has `MATTYPE`: A, and one has `MATTYPE:B`. I want to do something based on the result of `MATTYPE`. I'm doing a `for` loop and can do one thing to all the spheres in this example, but I want to be able to do two different things based on the result of `MATTYPE`.

Comment: maybe this helps you: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/elif-statements-python?utm_source=adwords_ppc&utm_campaignid=898687156&utm_adgroupid=48947256715&utm_device=c&utm_keyword=&utm_matchtype=b&utm_network=g&utm_adpostion=&utm_creative=332602034349&utm_targetid=aud-299261629574:dsa-429603003980&utm_loc_interest_ms=&utm_loc_physical_ms=9041948&gclid=CjwKCAjw_o-HBhAsEiwANqYhpzBpqCRzMZnpOnDJ7qxzhRb-qO9KheKht1ozPoLzd498ObCNi7nFnxoClzcQAvD_BwE

Comment: This helps, it doesn't go into how one might use an object's custom property to do something, which is the part I'm struggling with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the custom property in the form `object["property_name"]`, for example if you created a few spheres with different property `MATTYPE`, you could iterate over them to print something different for each value of the custom property in this way:

```
import bpy

spheres = [o for o in bpy.data.objects if o.name.startswith('Sphere')]

for sphere in spheres:
    mattype = sphere["MATTYPE"]
    if mattype == 0:
        color = "red"
    elif mattype == 1:
        color = "green"
    else:
        color = "blue"
    print(f'sphere "{sphere.name}" should have {color} color')
```

Comment: I can tell this is almost exactly what I need, I'm not actually working with spheres. During  mattype = sphere["MATTYPE"] it's going to throw an error up because "sphere" is going to be called any number of things. At the moment I'm doing

Comment: bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='VERTEX_PAINT')
        for object in context.selected_objects:
            mattype = object["MATTYPE"]
            if mattype == 0:
                context.view_layer.objects.active = object
                bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='VERTEX_PAINT')      
                bpy.data.brushes["Draw"].color = (0.057191, 0.292894, 1)
            else:
                bpy.data.brushes["Draw"].color = (1, 1, 1)

            bpy.ops.paint.vertex_color_set()
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')    ##

but its going to error where sphereis

Comment: @frog2nite better put that in question in code formatting. Keep in mind it doesn't matter that I named a variable on line 5 `sphere`, what matters is that on line 3 I'm looking for objects which name starts with a `Sphere`.

Comment: I think you've understood the problem dispite my fo-par lack of putting my question into coding formatting. I'll have the object selected, can I do something with that?

Comment: @frog2nite not sure what you mean, you can use `bpy.context.selected_objects` and `bpy.context.active_object`

Comment: When I try "mattype = bpy.context.active_object["MATTYPE"]" I get 'bpy_struct[key]: key "MATTYPE" not found''

Comment: @frog2nite perhaps not all of the objects you iterate over have this property. This is a Python problem at this point, you can use `get` or `try` to work around that problem.

Comment: You were right, I was looking at Data Object Properties, and not Object Properties. Thank you so much for your time :)